# Run community chef cookbook

Tags: chef, chef-solo, knife, berkshelf, chef-zero

I want to configure a mailserver on AWS with this cookbook: https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/postfix-dovecot

I have chef-client and chef-dk installed. I have downloaded the package and changed the cookbook attributes with my personal configurations.

What I need to run now? I tried: chef-client --local-mode -r "recipe[default]"

What's the correct way to run a community cookbook?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [chef-apply](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_apply.html)? It's a way to just run a cookbook rather than having an ongoing Chef setup.

Comment: chef-apply can only be executed for recipes and resources and not for cookbook policies.

Comment: Absolutely. But he's running the default recipe above.